# Why is javascript treating in function (local) variables as global (window) variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a javascript file which has in function (local) variables.  For example in the code below there are variables: countries, arr, india, usa, uae, australia, canada, kuwait etc.  When I launch my website all of these variables are accessible with window.xyz (e.g. window.countries, window.usa etc...).  I'm really confused why this would happen. I would really appreciate if someone can help me understand this.

```
MyApp.Helpers.LocationEducationHelper = function() {

function getPopularCountriesArray(){
    // var me = this;
    arr = [];
    countries = MyApp.getAllCountries();
    india = countries.get("IN");
    usa = countries.get("US");
    uae = countries.get("AE");
    australia = countries.get("AU");
    canada = countries.get("CA");
    kuwait = countries.get("KW");
    nz = countries.get("NZ");
    pk = countries.get("PK");
    russia = countries.get("RU");
    saudiArabia = countries.get("SA");
    southAfrica = countries.get("ZA")
    gb = countries.get("GB");
    arr.push(india, usa, gb, uae, canada, australia, nz, pk, kuwait, russia, saudiArabia, southAfrica);
    return arr
};
return {
    getPopularCountriesArray : getPopularCountriesArray
};};
```

Comment: You need a var statement; `var arr = []`,...

Comment: that has fixed it.  I tried using var. but apparantely countries was being set in two functions so var didn't work on my first try.  But adding var to both locations has fixed the issue.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable declared locally inside a function, without "var" treated as global variable. If you want to limit the scope use "var".

Global Declaration

```
var x = 4; //global variable
(function(){
    console.log(x); //returns 4
})();
console.log(x); //returns 4
```

Local declaration

```
(function(){
    var y = 4; //local variable
    console.log(y); //returns 4
})();
console.log(y); // Reference error y is not defined
```

Local without var

```
(function(){
    z = 4; //global variable
    console.log(z); //returns 4
})();
console.log(z); // returns 4
```

Answer (score 3):

add var
before each variable.
it's treated as global without it

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it like this.

```js
MyApp.Helpers.LocationEducationHelper = function() {

function getPopularCountriesArray(){
    // var me = this;
    var arr = [],
    countries = MyApp.getAllCountries(),
    india = countries.get("IN"),
    usa = countries.get("US"),
    uae = countries.get("AE"),
    australia = countries.get("AU"),
    canada = countries.get("CA"),
    kuwait = countries.get("KW"),
    nz = countries.get("NZ"),
    pk = countries.get("PK"),
    russia = countries.get("RU"),
    saudiArabia = countries.get("SA"),
    southAfrica = countries.get("ZA"),
    gb = countries.get("GB");

    arr.push(india, usa, gb, uae, canada, australia, nz, pk, kuwait, russia, saudiArabia, southAfrica);
    return arr
};
return {
    getPopularCountriesArray : getPopularCountriesArray
};};
```